# Magento CE 2.3.0 - Favicon and Logo upload issue

Tags: magento, magento2

When i try to upload Favicon or logo the following error comes up

A technical problem with the server created an error. Try again to continue what you were doing. If the problem persists, try again later.

**Background:**

I still haven't applied a theme and tried to upload favicon in HTML Head section (Content-Configuration)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252256/magento-2-3-favicon-and-logo-upload-does-not-take-hold

Answer (score 1):

File path : /vendor/magento/module-theme/view/adminhtml/ui_component/ design_config_form.xml

Find and replace :

```
<field name="header_logo_src" formElement="fileUploader">
To
<field name="header_logo_src" formElement="imageUploader">

<field name="head_shortcut_icon" formElement="fileUploader">
To
<field name="head_shortcut_icon" formElement="imageUploader">
```